# Time display format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I want display time in my MVC4 appication in a particular format.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:f}")]
public DateTime Eve_Date { get; set; }
```

I use the above format.

I want the date in the following format: `Sun, 11 July 2013, 5.30 PM`. How is this possible?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Did you find the format you wanted [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/az4se3k1.aspx)? If not, you can create your own format as is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code,

```
[DisplayFormat( DataFormatString="{0:ddd, d MMMM yyyy, hh.mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true )]
public DateTime Eve_Date { get; set; }
```

Usage,

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Eve_Date)
```

Comment: It is important to note that DisplayFormat will ONLY work in combination with EditorFor helper. If you try to use TextBoxFor helper applied to a DateTime property it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Eve_Date.ToString("ddd, dd MMMM yyyy, h.mm tt")
```